# Background Image NO display (Laravel,CSS)

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this image and its working on the main page of the web that Im working but when I try to put image for background in every page that this button redirects:

```
<a href="{{url('building', $building->id)}}"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Offices</a>
```

It doesnt show any background image I put the png file in the public folder

This is the css for the main page its working

```
.buildingbg{
  background-image: url("bldg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-y
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
```

Comment: What I see they are identical. So why do you need 2 css?

Comment: @halojoy sorry about that, I try using .buildingbg for both pages and the main is working but the other pages are not showing anythin

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is you are using page relative paths in your CSS.

It works on your home page because that is the site root. As you visit **/page** or some other page, because you are using page relative paths it will look for the image in the **/page** directory.

If it is working on your homepage, I am assuming you dropped **bldg.png** straight in the **public/** directory, so simply add a slash in front to use site relative image paths.

```
 background-image: url("/bldg.png");
```

You should organize your images into a folder within the public directory though.

Comment: Its still not working thou with the page i tried putting it in public and in image folder 

background-image: url("images/bldg.png");

Comment: You are still making page relative paths. Prefix that path with / (/images/bldg.png)

Comment: oh THANKS GOT IT MAN